# Requesting read receipt from VBA using gmail

Tags: excel, vba, gmail

I am trying to send a long list of emails through excel. I have everything working except that I need read receipts for each email. I have found some answers about read receipts using outlook but I need to use gmail. I have attached my code and it all works until the highlighted part. When I run it with that line I get the error: "438: Object doesn't support this property or method".

I am experienced with coding in R and SQL but I am fairly new with VBA so I apologize if this is a very simple issue. (I got most of this code from a different source)

```
Sub SendEmailUsingGmail()
    Dim NewMail As Object
    Dim mailConfig As Object
    Dim fields As Variant
    Dim msConfigURL As String
    On Error GoTo Err:

Set NewMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
Set mailConfig = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

    mailConfig.Load -1

    Set fields = mailConfig.fields
    
    
Dim RList As Range
Set RList = Range("A2", Range("a2").End(xlDown))

Dim path As String
path = "C:\filepath\"

    'Set All Email Properties
    For Each R In RList
    
        With NewMail
            .From = "mymail@gmail.com"
            .To = R.Offset(0, 2)
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .subject = "Testing Auto Mail for: " & R & " " & R.Offset(0, 1)
            .TextBody = "Text Body"
            .AddAttachment (path & R.Offset(0, 3))



             'This is the part that gives me the error

            .ReadReceiptRequested = True

             'This is the part that gives me the error


        End With

        msConfigURL = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration"
    
        With fields
            .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpusessl") = True             'Enable SSL Authentication
            .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpauthenticate") = 1          'SMTP authentication Enabled
            .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com" 'Set the SMTP server details
            .Item(msConfigURL & "/smtpserverport") = 465          'Set the SMTP port Details
            .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusing") = 2                 'Send using default setting
            .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendusername") = "mymail@gmail.com" 'Your gmail address
            .Item(msConfigURL & "/sendpassword") = "mypassword" 'Your password or App Password
            .Update                                               'Update the configuration fields
        End With
        NewMail.Configuration = mailConfig
        NewMail.Send
        
        MsgBox "Your emails have been sent", vbInformation
    
Exit_Err:
        'Release object memory
        Set NewMail = Nothing
        Set mailConfig = Nothing
        End
    
Err:
        Select Case Err.Number
        Case -2147220973  'Could be because of Internet Connection
            MsgBox "Check your internet connection." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Case -2147220975  'Incorrect credentials User ID or password
            MsgBox "Check your login credentials and try again." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        Case Else   'Report other errors
            MsgBox "Error encountered while sending email." & vbNewLine & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
        End Select
    
        Resume Exit_Err
Next R

End Sub
```

Comment: But without the error the code raises, I mean, commenting the respective line, does the code send the mail?

Comment: Yes the code works and sends the email if that line is removed.

Comment: I am asking that because I used to use this method some years before, but it started to raise an error about "login credentials" and something about no server availability... Probably, some configuration to be done in the gmail mail itself, but I start using other automation type.

Comment: You need to set Less secured apps access but this option has been discontinued since May 2022. What kind of gmail account do you have to accept that?

Comment: I am sending it from a company email. I can get admin privileges but I am unsure how that works.